# unable route traffic

Tags: networking, amazon-vpc, vpc-peering

## unable to ping from one instance to  another instance (Different AWS account) through VPC peering**

### As a part of learning I have created VPC peering between two different AWS account similar region

> 1.VPC A (vpc-0101125afe156bXXX) created in my account 1(Ohio) - with EC2  instance test1  (173.15.2.42 )has been launched.
> [image: VPC A]

> 2.VPC B (VPC-09abfe7f4c7c7cX7XX) created other Account child(Ohio)- with EC2 instance test2 (10.50.3.180) has been launched.

[image: VPC B]

> 3. VPC peering(pcx-ola8829c615XXXX) has created between two VPC of different accounts (let say region Ohio)

[image: VPC peering]

> 4.**To enable the traffic between two vpc,either VPC IP range has updated  in route tables**

[image: Route table VPC B]

[image: Route table VPC A]

Now

> 5. **ping test from from instance  test 2 (10.50.3.180) to  EC2-instance test1 (173.15.2.42 ) was successful**

```
*ubuntu@ip-10-50-3-180:~$* ping 173.15.2.42
PING 173.15.2.42 (173.15.2.42) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 173.15.2.42: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.649 ms
64 bytes from 173.15.2.42: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.723 ms
64 bytes from 173.15.2.42: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.763 ms
64 bytes from 173.15.2.42: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.767 ms
64 bytes from 173.15.2.42: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.680 ms
64 bytes from 173.15.2.42: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.694 ms
64 bytes from 173.15.2.42: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=0.916 ms
64 bytes from 173.15.2.42: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=0.670 ms
64 bytes from 173.15.2.42: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=0.733 ms
```

> 6. **Now I was try to ping  from Ec2 Instance test1 (173.15.2.42) to Ec2 instance test2  (10.50.3.180). It was showing nothing on the terminal.

```
[ec2-user@ip-173-15-2-42 ~]$ ping 10.50.3.180
```

7. 

I am able to ping an instance (test 2) residing in the  VPC of master account  to instance test 1 residing in child account and vice versa but I'm unable to ping that instance (test1) from an instance ( test2)residing in the master account  ?

8.
which configuration I was missing ???

Comment: Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers.  Remins to use text instead of the pictures. And dont use uneeded pig text sizes as it soubds like crying

Comment: this was my first question & I'll try to improve .....literally tnx for ur suggestion @djdomi

Comment: What OS are the instances, and are they configured to respond to pings? Is IPTables or UFW blocking you? Do Security Groups need modifying to allow the traffic? Are NACLs being used?